# How do I avoid starting multiple postgres instances on my machine

Tags: postgresql

Why do I see multiple postgres instances in my machine. I would like to stop + remove the older version of postgres permanently, how should I go about doing this.

```
 ps -ef | grep postgresql
postgres  1766     1  0 06:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf -c external_pid_file=/var/run/postgresql/9.1-main.pid
postgres  3398     1  0 06:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove, uninstall the postgres version via your package manager. 
Ex: `sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.1`

To temporarily disable, follow this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/582499/i-have-multiple-postgresql-servers-installed-how-do-i-disable-auto-boot-for-old